# Android action bar tabs inside navigation drawer fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer with fragments. Is there any possible way to implement action bar tabs in one the fragments while having navigation drawer just like in Google I/O 2014 app?:

http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/google-io-2014-app-4.png

I mean I need it at least look like action bar tabs (with swipe gesture). Because default viewPagerTabStrip really suck.

Thanks in Advance ;)

Answer (score 2):

yes..i have implemented the same in my app.
I also used `ViewPager`.

`<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), ActionBarActivity.this));
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
        }
    });

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Client");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Supplier");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab3.setText("Driver");
    tab3.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab4 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab4.setText("Owner");
    tab4.setTabListener(this);

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
    actionBar.addTab(tab4);

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

}
```

and also use the Fragment Adapter

```
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    Context context;
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context){
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(i == 0){
            fragment = new FragmentClass1(context);
        }else if(i == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentClass2(context);
        }else if(i == 2){
            fragment = new FragmentClass3(context);
        }else {
            fragment = new FragmentClass4(context);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

and for drawer, use this

`<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`
 //your code
`</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`

Comment: Actually, there is a few problems:
1. Navigation drawer is below the tabs and it should be only below action bar.
2. When you change fragment via navigation drawer, tabs do not disappear.
3. When coming back to viewPager fragment, tabs duplicates.
Have you got any solutions for these problems ?

Comment: i do not get such problems. i have edited my answer. check the functions i have added newly.

Comment: @enVGuy : Did you manage to solve the above mentioned problems? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Yep, but I did not used standard tabs. Google has code for that. I'm not at home, so I cannot search a link for you, but you can check Google I/O 2014 source code. They used these "custom" tabs there. Also there is a video in yoytube devbytes for that. If you will not find it write me a pm and I will search for that link later.